# Why's that vscode cant autocomplete exported objects on its own, from one file in another, in nodejs? Is it a performance feature?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, sequelize.js

## Problem

In my usecase, i maintain my database config/connections using `sequelize` in a separate file `models/index.js`. I `export` the database connection object(called `db`) so that other modules can connect to the database. But when I `require` the object in some other file, no auto-completions are shown for that object nor its corresponding properties.

## Context

This is how my part of my `models/index.js` file looks like, which i have done like the official [sequelize example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sequelize/express-example/master/models/index.js):-

```js
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config);
let db = {};
// for each of the files `file` in a dir...dynamically do(refer above linked example for details):-
let model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize);
db[model.name] = model; // type Sequelize.Model
// dynamic config over

// statically add
db.sequelize = sequelize; // type Sequelize
module.exports = db
```

This is how i have imported in another module:-

```js
const db = require("./models/index.js");
db.seq -------------------------------> where i try for auto-completion
```

## Expectation

When i `require` my database connection object `db` in another file, it should provide auto-completion for the properties i statically assigned, like `db.sequelize` should be a completion and further `db.sequelize.xxx`, where `xxx` is the corresponding sequelize methods and properties should also be auto-completed.

## What's the behavior now?

Typing `db.` doesn't show any valid auto-completions pertaining to the object `db`. Also `db.sequelize` has a type `any` for the `sequelize` part(so no further auto-completions), whereas I expected it to be `Sequelize`.

## What I have done?

- Explicitly added `jsdoc`, thinking that's the only way to make the auto-completions work, but to no use:-

```js
/**
* @typedef {import('sequelize').Sequelize} Sequelize
*/

const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
/**
 * @type {Sequelize}
 */
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config);
/**
 * key : string -> Name of the Sequelize.Model | 'sequelize'
 * value : Either one of the Models or Sequelize object
 * @type {Object.<string,(Sequelize|Sequelize.Model)>}
 * @property {Sequelize} sequelize
 * @example
 * db = { User: db.User , seqeuelize : sequelize}
 */
let db = {};
// rest of the dynamic processing and adding Sequelize.Model to db
db.sequelize = sequelize;
module.exports = db
```

- Added a `jsconfig.json` with following content, but that was also futile:-

```js
{
  // NOTE THAT, this file resides within my src/server/ directory where all the js files exists
  // the models/index.js resides within src/server
  // I maintain another jsconfig for src/client
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators":true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*"],
    },
  },
  "include": ["./**/*"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your object `let db = {};` to `let db = {sequelize: null};`, you will get intellisense to work as intended.

Comment: That would only allow to auto-complete the property `db.sequelize` in another file. But the type of `db.sequelize` is still `any`, which is not desired. It should be of type `Sequelize`, so that i could get further auto-completions on `db.sequelize.xxx`. I could explicitly add a jsdoc type for Sequelize in the file where i import `db`. But the what destroy the purpose. I already declared sequelize as `Sequelize` type in jsdoc, in my `models`. So when importing, shouldn't the type be maintained?

Comment: Shouldn't your example inside JSDoc look like `db = { User: db.User , seqeuelize : Sequelize}`. Sequelize with capital S.

Comment: No. `Sequelize` with capital `S`, is the main class, entry point. `sequelize` with small 's' is the object of `Sequelize`, with my custom `config`, which includes dialect, username, env etc. Thus exporting and using `sequelize` with small 's' is useful in other modules, whereas `Sequelize` with capital 'S' can always be imported directly from the sequelize package in any other modules if necessary. Although adding an extra property `Sequelize` with value `Sequelize` to `db` wouldn't be a bad decision, it's not relevant to our discussion here i think.

Comment: Well, I try replicating your use-case on my VS Code and everything worked perfectly. I don't know how much this will help but I made this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-wave-4q6ry?file=/src/index.js) and it shows both intellisense as well as autocomplete working on the files.

Comment: This makes sense. I'm thinking, maybe its a problem with one of the dependencies or I should explicitly upgrade the typescript-js language server to newer version. It's not a settings problem in vscode, i checked by turning all custom settings on and off. Thanks for your input. This helps to confirm that the problem is with my vscode itself, not my code. Can you tell me your vscode version and build?

Comment: Version: 1.45 and the lastest build

Comment: weird. im using the same insiders build.

Comment: Restarting the TypeScript Language Server has helped me a lot many times.